# htmlunit for php or equivalent

Tags: php, htmlunit

I am writing a spider script,and I need the spider to get content generated by javascript,I heard htmlunit will execute javascript.My script is php,how do I get work with htmlunit?
Is there a php equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798331/is-there-an-htmlunit-port-for-php/6799372#6799372). I'm inclined to think that's still true. That answer says that you [PHPUnit with Selenium RC](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html) may work.

You may also be able to use [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/).

The other option would be to hand the page response over to a command-line call to Java to do the dirty work, using htmlunit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325631/selenium-vs-simpletest-vs-watin  This link told SimpleTest does not support javascript,command-line call is a choice.Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyIlenloa This is a really old answer, I would probably recommend looking at a [headless browser](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) these days.

Comment: thank you Jared I am checking that out as well, it could be a good alternative for me, HtmlUnit headless browser is nice too, if using Java isn't a problem.